# Laravel model binding not working for delete

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am asking a very basic question, and i searched for more than two hours, but still i was not able to fix it. I am new to laravel, and trying to read their example for Tasks. But some how the delete is not working. 
Below is my code for route:

```
Route::delete('/task/{task}', function(\AltafBlog\Task $task) {
     $task->delete();
     return redirect('/');
});
```

And below is my form for delete:

```
<form action="{{url('/task', [$task->id])}}" method="post">
   {{csrf_field()}}
   {{method_field('DELETE')}}
   <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Now when i click on delete button, it does not delete the item in the table. Also, i dont get any error message. Adding new items and listing them are working fine. 
I am not sure what i am doing wrong. Can anybody suggest what is going on there?

**Update:** After updating to laravel 5.2, the model binding is working, but the Validator is not working in post route. the post route is as below:

```
Route::post('/task', function(Request $request) {
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'title'  =>  'required|max:255',
]);
if($validator->fails())
{
    return redirect('/')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
}
    $task = new Task();
    $task->title = $request->title;
    $task->active = 1;
    $task->save();
    return redirect('/');
});
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you get the `$task` instance in the callback?

Comment: task id you are passing but not using in route

Comment: @vijay4vijju  if he using laravel 5.2 there are implicit binding

Comment: I am following this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart#deleting-the-task . In implicit model binding, it will automatically load the model with that id.

Comment: @vijay4vijju. Just checked and i am using laravel 5.1.24. How i can update it to 5.2?

Comment: @AltafHussain here the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade

Comment: Ok, let me try that.

Comment: @vijay4vijju perfect. I updated to 5.2 and is working fine now. Can you please submit a detailed answer so i can accept. thanks

Comment: @AltafHussain I suppose you wrote it for me. Create another topic and we will try to find solution for your problem :)

Comment: oh sorry yes, i meant it for you. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in Laravel version. Laravel 5.1.24 doesn't have implicit bindings.

So, if you want to use it you should use (or upgrade) Laravel 5.2.*
[Upgrading To 5.2.0 From 5.1](http://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade)

Answer (score 1):

I believe there could be a couple of reasons why this won't work.

Firstly when your parameter $task-id is pulled through your route, it will be the variable $task. You are then overwriting this variable with an instance of task. You are then running the delete method, and it wouldn't throw an error. Try changing your code to the following

Your route

```
Route::delete('/task/{taskID}', function(\AltafBlog\Task $task, $taskID) {
    $task->find($taskID);
    $task->delete();
    return redirect('/');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to add `->all()` after `$request`.

Your code should look like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request, [
    'title'  =>  'required|max:255',
]);
```

Or you can try this:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'title'  =>  'required|max:255',
]);
```